# How to show rectangle on WPF canvas from c sharp file

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I know how to create a rectangle in the WPF xaml, then edit it in the c sharp file. What I'm interested in is creating the rectangle in the c sharp file, displaying it on the WPF canvas, then being able to manipulate it. My friends and I are working on a game, and we'd like to be able to generate new objects from the source code on the fly. Any help would be great :)

Comment: You should not be doing that, instead use data binding and data-templating, anyway; read about those things [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. Provided that you have a Canvas like in this XAML

```
<Window ...>
    <Canvas Name="canvas" />
</Window>
```

you can play around with code like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle
{
    Fill = Brushes.Red,
    Width = 100,
    Height = 100
};

Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, 100);
canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```